# Creating a "ref tuple"

Tags: c#, c#-11.0

I am trying to use C# 11 ref struct/fields to create a "ref tuple", that is a type that holds multiple `ref`s.

```
ref struct RefTuple<T1, T2> {
  public ref T1 Item1;
  public ref T2 Item2;

  public RefTuple(ref T1 item1, ref T2 item2)
  {
    Item1 = ref item1;
    Item2 = ref item2;
  }

  public bool Equals(RefTuple<T1, T2> o) {
    return Equals(Item1, o.Item1) && Equals(Item2, o.Item2);
  }

  public override bool Equals(object o) {
    return o is RefTuple<T1, T2> rt && Equals(rt);
  }

  public override int GetHashCode() {
    retrun HashCode.Combine(Item1?.GetHashCode() ?? 0, Item2?.GetHashCode() ?? 0);
  }

  public static bool operator ==(RefTuple<T1, T2> obj1, RefTuple<T1, T2> obj2) {  
    return obj1.Equals(obj2);
  }

  public static bool operator !=(RefTuple<T1, T2> obj1, RefTuple<T1, T2> obj2) {
    return !obj1.Equals(obj2);
  }
}
```

The idea is I can then initialize and pass an object of type `RefTuple<T1, T2>` to a function using a `ref`, and that function can then change `Item1` etc which will modify the original ref used when initializing the `RefValue`.

Problems:

1. `Equals(object o)` above *does not compile* seems the `is` operator does not work with ref structs ? I am not sure how to correctly implement it.
2. `Equals(object o)` also shows "Nullability of type of parameter 'o' doesn't match overridden member" which I am not able to resolve. (code has nullability enabled)
3. `Equals(RefTuple<T1, T2> o)` is using `object.Equals` but I believe that may not be efficient as it may end up boxing. I tried instead `Item1.Equals(o.Item1) && Item2.Equals(o.Item2)` but then get the nullability warnings above.

Comment: "2.": Simply write signature as `Equals(object? o)`. However, implementing it ("1.") is - AFAIK - not possible, since `ref struct`s don't support boxing. All examples I have seen so far, either don't care about overwriting this method (internal or interop types) or throw `NotSupportException` and resort to custom Equals or operator== implementation. Someone else might be able to provide a more profound answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. There's some [limits](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/ref-struct) when using a `ref struct`, one of them is:

   > A `ref struct` can't be boxed to System.ValueType or System.Object.

   The parameter `o` in `Equals(object o)` can never be the type of `RefTuple`, so you can simply return false.
2. The [signature](https://source.dot.net/#System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/ValueType.cs,25) of this method in the base class is:

   ```
   bool Equals(object? obj)
   ```

   The overridden method need match it.

   ```
   public override bool Equals(object? o) => false;
   ```
3. Even if you call `Item1.Equals(o.Item1)`, you are still calling the method `Equals(object)`, boxing cannot be ignored. The built-in [`ValueTuple`](https://source.dot.net/#System.Private.CoreLib/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/ValueTuple.cs,479) class uses `EqualityComparer<T1>.Default`, maybe this is for reference.

   ```
   public bool Equals(RefTuple<T1, T2> o) {
      return EqualityComparer<T1>.Default.Equals(Item1, o.Item1)
          && EqualityComparer<T2>.Default.Equals(Item2, o.Item2);
   }
   ```